# terminating a command in perl based on conditions

Tags: perl, shell

I have a lot of TNS names from which I have to obtain host names and port numbers using the TNSPing utility.

```
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
  chomp $line;
  print "TNS: $line\n";
  my $output = `tnsping $line | grep -Eo  "HOST=[A-Za-z0-9.\-]*com?|PORT=[0-9]+"`;
  print "$output\n";
  print "----------------\n\n";
}
```

The output of a `tnsping` looks something like this

> ```
> TNS Ping Utility for Linux: Version 11.1.0.0.2 on 15-FEB-2009 14:46:28
>
> Copyright (c) 1997, 2009 Oracle Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> Used parameter files:
> Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
> Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL =
> TCP)(HOST = sampleserver.com)(PORT = 1521))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME =
> sales.us.example.com)))
> OK (10 msec)
> ```

The code works fine for most of the TNS entries, but for certain entries, The `tnsping` command is **not exiting** and hence gets struck. I tried running one of these entries manually, I found out that they are printing to stdout but for some reason the tnsping utility is not exiting.

Now my question is, How can I modify the script so that it moves to the next entry once I get the host and port data, irrespective of whether the `tnsping` utility exits or not ?

My current understanding is that only when the `tnsping` utility exits, grep will work (i,e it's not continous).

I am also open to any alternative approaches.

Comment: You can add a timeout to your command `timeout 20s your command`.  Also, you can use `command & sleep 10 ; kill $!`. If you command doesn't complete in 10 seconds it will be killed. .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest using `IO::Select` and `can_read`. I would also suggest - don't run `grep` do it within perl.

Something like this:

```
while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {
   chomp $line;
   print "TNS: $line\n";

   my $pid = open( my $output, '-|', 'tnsping $line' );
   my $select = IO::Select->new($output);

   my $host;
   my $port;
   #check if the FH is readable, with a 5s timeout. 
   while ( $select->can_read(5) ) {
      my $line = <$output>; 
      $line =~ m/HOST\s*=\s*([A-Za-z0-9.\-]*com?)/ and $host = $1;
      $line =~ m/PORT\s*=\s*([0-9]+)/ and $port = $1;
   }
   close($output);
   print $host, "\n";
   print $port, "\n";
   print "$output\n";
   print "----------------\n\n";
}
```

I'd suggest as a style point - `$fh` isn't a great variable name.